# timestamp of most recent midnight from timestamp

Tags: ruby

I have a timestamp

```
timestamp = Time.now.utc.to_f
```

I need to find the timestamp at midnight UTC the same day:

```
t = Time.at timestamp
Time.at(((t - t.hour * 3600).to_f / 3600).to_i * 3600).to_f
```

is there a way to get the same timestamp without having to convert the original `timestamp` to `Time` object? In a way similar to getting a timestamp rounded to the most recent hour:

```
(timestamp / 3600).to_i * 3600
```

Comment: no, this is pure Ruby.

Comment: Midnight local time? Or UTC?

Comment: I have edited the question. midnight UTC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the UTC timestamp starts on January 1, 1970 at **midnight** UTC, just do:

```
timestamp - timestamp % (3600*24)
```

That will give you the timestamp at the last midnight UTC.

To adjust for your time zone, just add or remove the corresponding number of hours **before** calculating the modulo and then add or remove them back to get the corresponding UTC timestamp.

Comment: it just occurred to me: is not it the same as `(timestamp / (24 * 3600)).to_i * 24 * 3600` for UTC? So the formula is essentially the same as the one for the nearest hour.

Comment: Yes it is the same result and the same approach.